# Crop image and extend with blurred background

Tags: image, background, crop, blur

I really like how ***`hangtime.com`*** crops their images to fit and then add a blurred background to them as [here](http://images.hangtime.com/events/640x480/510274419074721_c65d5efcf99378d640793e10a775284b389b241c).

Does someone know how this is done?

Answer (score 0):

here's an [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) command line that should do something similar:

```
convert ( -blur 0x50 -gravity center -resize 640x480^ -crop 480x480+0+0 -resize 640x480! a.jpg  ) -gravity east ( -background none -size 480x320 gradient:black-none -rotate 270 ) -composite -gravity west ( -background none -size 480x320 gradient:black-none -rotate 90 ) -composite -gravity center ( a.jpg  -resize 640x480^ -crop 470x480+0+0 )  -composite output.jpg
```